# How can I estimate how many Cassandra nodes I need for a given read requests per second load?

Tags: cassandra

I wish to estimate how many cassandra storage nodes I would need to serve a specific number of reads per second.

My node specs are 32 cores, 256GB ram, 10Gbps NIC, 10x 6TB HDDs. Obviously SSDs would be much more preferrable, but these are not available in this instance.

I have around 5x10^11 values of 1kB each = 500TB of values to serve, **at a rate of 100,000 read requests per second.** The distribution of these requests is completely even, ie, ram capacity caching will have no effect.

If we assume that each HDD can sustain ~100 IOps, then **I could expect that I need at least ~ 100 nodes to serve this read load - correct?**

I also estimate that I would need at least ~ 20 machines for the total storage with a replication factor of 2, plus overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It's a really broad question - you need to try to test your machines with tools, like, [NoSQLBench](http://nosqlbench.io/) that was specially built for such tasks.

Typical recommendation is to store ~1Tb of data per Cassandra node (including replication). You need to take into account other factors, like, how long it will take to replace the node in the cluster, or add new one - the speed of streaming is directly proportional to size of data on disk.

HDDs are really not recommended if you want to have low latency answers. I have a client with ~150Tb spread over ~30 machines with HDDs, with a lot of writes although, and read latencies regularly are going above 0.5 second, and higher.  You need to take into account that Cassandra requires random access to data, and head of HDD simply couldn't move so fast to serve requests.